# How to combine two resources value in one in gridview in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, resources, globalization

I would like to combine and use two resources value in headertext.

**Example Code for one resources value:**

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText='<%$ Resources:titles, approve %>'  ...
```

**Result:**

```
Title
-------
Approve
```

**Tried Code:**

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText='<%$ Resources:titles, approve %><%$ Resources:titles, deny%>'  ...
```

ofcourse doesn't work..

**Expected Result:**

```
Title
-----
Approve/Deny
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is not possible in the aspx definition of the gridview.

What you can do as an alternative is do it in the code-behind file like so:

```cs
grvTheGrid.Columns[1].HeaderText = Resources.Titles.approve + Resources.titles.deny;
```